# Fund matrix using Surf with Ransac in Matlab

Tags: matlab, surf, computer-vision

I'm trying to implement SURF with Ransac for fundamental(F) matrix estimation in Matlab. Then I calculated epipoles as null spaces of F matrix. I used OpenSURF from [File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28300-opensurf-including-image-warp) and Ransac from [Peter's Kovesi page](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/Research/MatlabFns/index.html). However when two images are similar the epipoles doesn't become unstable as they should. Can someone provide me Matlab example of these two working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone need this information, great number of examples using these two, one can find in [Peter Corke's](http://petercorke.com/Book.html) new book!